# jQuery UI Datepicker - Exclude Disabled Dates in min/maxdate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the jQuery UI datepicker and am using the noWeekends method on beforeShowDay to disable weekends from being selectable. In conjunction with this, I'd like to set a min and max date of 5 and -5 days from todays date.

The problem I'm having though, is I do NOT want weekends to be included in that 5 day span. I want it to be a min and max of 5 SELECTABLE days, not days in general. I only want dates that are not disabled to be calculated in the min and maxdate range.

Example: If there are 2 days disabled within the last 45 days, the mindate of 45 would actually be 47 (if the disabled dates were included).

http://jsfiddle.net/corydorning/8mp5W/

```
// what I need
$('.date').datepicker({
    maxDate: 5, // 5 selectable days
    minDate: -5, // -5 selectable days
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});
```

NOTE: I'm looking for a solution that takes into ANY disabled date, not just weekends. I just used weekends for this example as it's the most easily represented and is built-in to jQuery UI.

Comment: Wouldn't changing your min and max to seven from five, combined with the .noWeekends solve your problem?

Comment: yes. but if using a min/max date of 45 you can't manually calculate the number of days to add to min or max date for each day of the week.

Comment: Hi, have your problem has been solved?

Answer (score 2):

Edit the `beforeShowDay` function like so:

```
$('.date').datepicker({
    maxDate: 5,
    minDate: -5,
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        //disable Tuesdays
        return [(day != 2), ""];
    }
});
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8mp5W/1/

Using that paradigm, you should be able to create a list of dates that you don't wish to show as well (vs. just Tuesdays, etc).

I think this answers your question on how to gain the ability to customize your available dates.

### EDIT

The following javascript sets the `minDate` by counting backward from today's date and skipping the weekend dates `[0,6]` as it runs a tally.  It stops when it reaches your desired # of days back.

It could be made more efficient, and should be parameterized, etc, but I'll leave tuning and customizing to you.  Finding `maxDate` would work in the same way, but advance the date forward instead.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.date').datepicker({
    minDate: findMin (),
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
  });
});


function findMin () {
        var today = new Date();
        var invalidWeekdays = [0,6]; //weekdays to disregard
        var validDaysPrior = 5; //number of days to count back

        var i = 0;
        while (i < validDaysPrior) {
           today.setDate(today.getDate()-1); //decrement day
           console.log("today is", today);
           var todayWeekday = today.getDay();
           if ( jQuery.inArray(todayWeekday, invalidWeekdays) < 0 ) {
               console.log(todayWeekday + " is valid");
               i++;
           } else {
               console.log(todayWeekday + " is NOT valid");
           }
        }
        console.log(validDaysPrior + " valid days ago occurred on " + today);
        return today;
}
```

Comment: I'm not having a problem disabling dates. I have that completed. What I'm having issues with is jQuery UI counting disabled dates as part of the min and maxdate.

Using your example, i do not want Tuesday to be counted in the 25 days you set as a max and min. It should be 25 days from today's date, not including tuesday which would really be 28 days, since 3 tuesdays are disabled in that span.

Comment: Couldn't you just iterate over a nearby set of dates and exclude the ones you don't want, while incrementing the counter to reach 25, for example?  Be specific in your request.  It seemed that you wanted to understand the approach for how to manipulate dates, and the approach I've offered is sound.

Comment: I tried to be as specific as possible. I've tried the enumeration to count the number of disabled days, but is still problematic. Say I choose a minDate of 45 days. if I count the days that are disabled between todays date and 45 days ago (say there's 20) and add that number to the 45, that would mean my 45 should be 65. Problem with this is that I have not accounted for the days that are disabled between 45 and 65 now. /scratching-my-head

Comment: My question pertains only to calculating the min and maxdate so that disabled dates are NOT counted in the given min/maxdate range. I edited my question so hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: Hi Marc, your fiddle is very helpful. i want to disable more than one dates which i got from database. how can i write more than one instead of 2 or 3 there. i tried by using 2,3 but it is not working.i have the dates in a var like var open_days = 2,3;

it will be very helpful if you can suggest something about this.

Comment: From your fiddle, instead of blocking Tuesdays, how could I block 06/11/2020, 06/12/2020, and 06/13/2020?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code: get_date() is calling through ajax in my code. you can create an array.And enter a date there.

```
window.natDays = [];
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  async : false,
  url : rootPath + '/get_date',
  data : "ajax=true",
  success : function(msg) {
    var a = $.parseJSON(msg);
    $i = 0;
    $.each(a, function(key, value) {
      arr = (value.Date['date']).split('-');
      arr2[key] = new Array(value.Date['month'], arr[2],
          value.Date['occassion']);
    });
    natDays = arr2;
  }
});
var dateMaxforswitch = new Date();
dateMinforswitch.setDate(dateMinforswitch.getDate()
    + (dateMinforswitch.getHours() >= 17 ? 1 : 0));
dateMaxforswitch.setDate(dateMaxforswitch.getDate()
    + (dateMaxforswitch.getHours() >= 17 ? 1 : 0));
AddBusinessDays(dateMaxforswitch, 25);

function AddBusinessDays(curdate, weekDaysToAdd) {
  while (weekDaysToAdd > 0) {
    curdate.setDate(curdate.getDate() + 1);
    // check if current day is business day
    if (noWeekendsOrHolidays(curdate)[0]) {
      weekDaysToAdd--;
    }
  }
}

function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
  var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
  if (noWeekend[0]) {
    return nationalDays(date);
  } else {
    return noWeekend;
  }
}
function nationalDays(date) {
  for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {// alert(natDays[i][2]);
    if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1 && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
      return [ false, natDays[i][2] + '_day' ];
    }
  }
  return [ true, '' ];
}
```